# Read part of a file in C

Tags: c

I've spent some time searching the internet for an answer, but still didn't find any help. I'd like to read a .txt file and store the values in int width, int height and char message.

**Update: Furthermore I'd like to make the program adaptable in case if the order of the values in read.txt is different.**

read.txt

```
width 40
height 20
message "Hello"
```

main.c file

```
FILE *file_in = fopen("read.txt", "r");

int width;
int height;
char *message = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);

fscanf(file_in, "width %d", &width);
fscanf(file_in, "height %d", &height);
fscanf(file_in, "message %s", message);

printf("width %d\n", width);
printf("height %d\n", height);

fclose(file_in);
return 0;
```

output

```
width 0
height 0
```

I'm trying to get the correct output. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is this C or C++ ? Please choose one.

Comment: Seems that you need to use `fprinf` instead of `printf` to write output to the file...

Comment: Note that you read into width twice.

Comment: Unrelated, but if the message buffer size is known at compile time, why not allocate it on the stack? 255 bytes will definitely fit on it (`char message[255]`).

Comment: Thanks errikos, corrected that. EdgarRokyan you're right, just updated the question. SirDarius, sorry, was by mistake.

Comment: `fscanf(file_in, "height %d", &height);` fails because the previously line's `'\n`' is left over.  `fscanf(file_in, " height %d", &height);` will fix that.  Same for `" message %s"`  add space

Comment: chux has your answer.  Essentially you have left over carriage returns in your text file.  Your method wouldn't be my preferred choice.  It's a bit inflexible.  I have had great success with reading each line out of the file and processing it (the line) according to it's contents

Comment: regarding this line: `char *message = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by ` makes no change in the resulting value.  Suggest removing that expression  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: `FILE *file_in = fopen("read.txt", "r");` always check (!=NULL) the returned value before using it to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem, you must post code that cleanly compiles.  Otherwise how do you expect us to debug your runtime problem?  The posted code is just fragments and we are not mind readers so could only guess as to what your actual code looks like

Comment: regarding this line: `fscanf(file_in, "message %s", message);`,  will fail, due to the newline sequence, left over from the input of `height`. This can be fixed by inserting a space at the beginning of the format string.  I.E. `" message %s"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read the field name into a variable. Then use that to determine which variable to write the value into:

```
char field_name[20];

while(fscanf(file_in, "%s", field_name) == 1) {
    if (strcmp(field_name, "width") == 0) {
        fscanf(file_in, "%d\n", &width);
    } else if (strcmp(field_name, "height" == 0) {
        fscanf(file_in, "%d\n", &height);
    } else if (strcmp(field_name, "message") == 0) {
        fscanf(file_in, "%s\n", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will fail for two reasons.  1) any left over white space, like a newline or space, will cause the reading of the `field_name` to fail.  2) the reading of the `message` will fail for the same reason.  Suggest inserting a space at the beginning of each of those two format strings   Also, always limit the length of a %s input, so the input buffer cannot be overrun.  I.E. `fscanf(file_in, " %19s", field_name)` and `fscanf( file_in, " %254s\n", message)`

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
fscanf(file_in, "width %d", &width);
fscanf(file_in, "height %d", &width);
```

should be

```
char temBuffer[32];

fscanf(file_in, "%s %d\n", tempBuffer, &width);
fscanf(file_in, "%s %d\n", tempBuffer, &height);
```

BTW to write to `out.txt` file you have to use `fprintf`

```
fprintf(file_out, "width %d\n", width);
fprintf(file_out, "height %d\n", height);
```

**EDIT**
This is a way to check the string value e assign the int value to the right variable.

```
char temBuffer[32];
int tempInt;
fscanf(file_in, "%s %d\n", tempBuffer, &tempInt);

if (strcmp(tempBuffer, "width") == 0)
{
   width = tempInt;
}
else if (strcmp(tempBuffer, "height") == 0)
{
   height = tempInt;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
**Very importand:** you mallocated message string. You must call free, [c](/questions/tagged/c) talking..

Comment: Ok, and `fprintf()` for the output ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that is working. But how does the program know, if the first value is width? How can I check if the first value is width and not height?

Comment: @michithebest You could check it evaluating the content of tempBuffer. You could use strcmp function

Comment: For the record, using "width %d" as the scanf format string should work.

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ - "Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread."

Comment: @LPs Could you edit your answer to make it still work if height or message comes before width in read.txt? :)

Comment: @michithebest I edited. You still have to loop the file until the end, or until all variable are found.

Comment: @NadavL I know it. I guessed what OP is asking now. BTW is quite strange to read a file and put its content to another file if you know where each string an value are placed within the source file. My personal opinion is that is always better to read the whole content without predict string or whatever.

Comment: I'm with you on it too, but it's important to stress that what he did can and will work - there are several ways to skin a cat - also, scanf will return error code if strings not matching, so it might be another way to check format validity of input file.

Comment: disagree with `fscanf(file_in, "%s %d", tempBuffer, &width); fscanf(file_in, "%s %d", tempBuffer, &height);` as that loads in values without qualificaitons.  OP;s original approach with `fscanf(file_in, " width %d", tempBuffer, &width);
fscanf(file_in, " height %d", tempBuffer, &height);` does at least that.  That likely needed a leading space to consume the `'\n`

Comment: "Mallocated?"  I feel like I want to up vote you just for inventing a cool word. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use your out file pointer using [fprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) to write the contents to a file. The width and height values in your output file are 0 because you never wrote the values read from the input file. Change your code to look like below -

```
FILE *file_in = fopen("read.txt", "r");
FILE *file_out = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
char line[80]; // assuming 80 is max size of the line in file
int width;
int height;

char *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
char *temp2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);

while(fgets(line, 80, file_in) != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(line, "%s %s", temp1, temp2) == 2)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp1, "width") == 0)
        {
            width = atoi(temp2);
        }
        if (strcmp(temp1, "height") == 0)
        {
            height = atoi(temp2);
        }
    }
}
fprintf(file_out, "%s %d\n", "width", width);
fprintf(file_out, "%s %d\n", "height", height);

free(temp1);
free(temp2);
fclose(file_in);
fclose(file_out);
return 0;
```

Comment: This is the best approach, Strongly recommend to only use fgets()` for input and ditch `fprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You read width twice if you look carefully our code.
additionally you should add the '\n', the new line character at the end of the fscanf format string. Also you are printing to the screen, if you want to write the output file use fprintf() and finally call free() to release the memory you allocated with malloc.
Your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *file_in = fopen("read.txt", "r");
   FILE *file_out = fopen("out.txt", "w+");

   int width;
   int height;
   char *message = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);

   fscanf(file_in, "width %d\n", &width);
   fscanf(file_in, "height %d\n", &height);
   fscanf(file_in, "message %s\n", message);

   fprintf(file_out, "width %d\n", width);
   fprintf(file_out, "height %d\n", height);

   fclose(file_in);
   fclose(file_out);
   free(message);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding the `'\n'` to the format is a reasonable idea to consume _any_ white-space like `'\n'`, etc.  and that fixes one of OP's problems.  Unclear why someone down-voted this.

Answer (score 0):

Code failed because `fscanf(file_in, "height %d\n", &height);` did not first consume the proceeding's line `'\n'` and code did not check the result of `fscanf()`.

Instead use `fgets()` as answered by [vk239](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364031/2410359).

If really want to stay with `fscanf()`, incorporate error handling, add a leading space before keywords to consume prior white-space, limit string input.

```
FILE *file_in = fopen("read.txt", "r");
if (file_in == NULL) Handle_Error();

int width;
int height;
char message[255];

if (fscanf(file_in, " width%d", &width) != 1) Handle_Error();
if (fscanf(file_in, " height%d", &height) != 1) Handle_Error();
if (fscanf(file_in, " message%254s", message != 1) Handle_Error();

printf("width %d\n", width);
printf("height %d\n", height);

fclose(file_in);
return 0;
```